# what is a web service framework in plain English

Tags: web-services, web

I've being searching online about it for quite a while, but all I got is the information about web services, APIs, web services protocols..... Can someone plz tell what a web service is and what it can do in plain English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web service is a service delivered on the web.

By web we technically mean mostly the HTTP protocol.

Service can be anything: it can be a page for users to view, but it can also be, like in the documents you saw, a way for programs to perform operations

Programs use the web and connect to the service onto interfaces made for programs (not for humans).

Such interfaces are named Application Programming Interfaces, API. But sometimes the web service is complex and requires a *protocol*, a specific way to be operated.

**So a web service API is simply an interface for programs to operate a service through the web.**

And what is a webservice framework?  It's an ensemble of tools and libraries used to deploy a webservice.

As a webservice developer, a framework is like a tons of features already developed/thought-out that you can use in your own way to deliver your webservice faster. Examples of features handled by frameworks: client-server messaging, authentication and sessions management, files operations, etc.

Comment: thx for your answer. But I'm asking about web service framework, may you talk about it plz?